# I need a simple equation to calculate the probability of collision in IEEE 802.15.6

Tags: networking, routes, probability, collision, ieee

I've recently been reading through papers for my Ph.D. and I've come
to what seems to me as a dead-end. I'm working on IEEE 802.15.6 for
WBAN and I want a simple equation to calculate the probability of collision in wireless body networks when changing the number of nodes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Non-programming networking questions are off topic and should be asked on Network Engineering, Super User or Server Fault (other Stack Exchange Websites) instead. This site would be appropriate for questions concerning unique networking needs in support of software development. Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to find out what questions are accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.